# Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA) with UCommerce?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ucommerce

I tried to install the Sitecore Experience Accelerator and Ucommerce in Sitecore 8.2 update 4 but I get the error below.

[image]

I get the error on the last package that I install. Whether It is ucommerce or Sitecore Experience Accelerator.

Has anyone tried Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA) with UCommerce?

**Details below are the sitecore packages that I use:**

Sitecore 8.2 update 4 or Sitecore 8.2 update 3

Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.0 to 1.4

Latest version of ucommerce-for-sitecore-7.7.1.17180

Sitecore power Shell 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SXA and Ucommerce is not comaptible as of this moment according to this ticket: http://eureka.ucommerce.net/#!/question/2280

"Hello Joseph,
I managed to reproduce the issue, and it appears that unfortunately currently we are not compatible with the SXA, and it is not possible to install Ucommerce alongside it. The issue seems to be related to Ucommerce requesting the 'Anonymous' user, which is not returned correctly.
We will be looking into the issue to see if we can solve it for future releases.
Thank you for bringing this to our attention!
Kind regards,
David"